# Ajax Request in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to Ajax, I am trying to fetch data from database with an ajax call using jquery.

I have a list of country tabs and I am trying to display data when there is an user action

Here is my code sample, at the moment it is saying there is a null system reference.

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id, string searchTerm)
        {
            // Do we have a search term
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
            {
                // decode the searchTerm as we dont want to search for encoded bits
                searchTerm = Decode(searchTerm);
            }
        var a = _mRepository.GetMyId(id);
        if (a == null)
        {
            return View("NotFound");
        }


       // Here we need to get list of countries for the selected manufacturer

        var c = _mwRepository.Getcountries(id);

        ViewData["Countries"] = c.ToArray();



        // Now we need list of products for the manufacturer countries and this is an Ajax call to database so that it fetches data only when there is a user action
        foreach (var country in c)
        {
            var p = _productRepository.GetAllCurrentProductsForManufacturerCountry(id, 
               country.Id);

        }
            if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                                  ViewData["ManufacturerCountryProducts"] = 

                                  p.ToArray();
            }
```

Comment: Debug and tell us where is the NRE would be nice ;) By the way, your last foreach certainly doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks @RaphaëlAlthaus, I am not sure if that is right or not, So here I am trying to fetch data from databse, do i need to fetch that in my view?

Comment: It's just that you replace the content of `ViewData["ManufacturerCountryProducts"]` at every loop. Not sure that's wanted. Use a list, addRange results (by country), and assign the list (or array) to ViewData out of the foreach loop would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class CountryProducts
{
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public List<Product> ProductsList { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details( int id, string searchTerm )
{
    // Do we have a search term
    if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty( searchTerm ) )
    {
        // decode the searchTerm as we dont want to search for encoded bits
        searchTerm = Decode( searchTerm );
    }
    var a = _mRepository.GetMyId( id );
    if ( a == null )
    {
        return View( "NotFound" );
    }

    // Here we need to get list of countries for the selected manufacturer
    List<Country> countriesList = _mwRepository.Getcountries( id );

    var data = new List<CountryProducts>();
    if ( countriesList != null )
    {
        foreach (var country in countriesList)
        {
            List<Product> products = _productRepository.GetAllCurrentProductsForManufacturerCountry(id,
                                                                                                    country.Id);
            data.Add(new CountryProducts() {Country = country, ProductsList = products});
        }
    }

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        ViewData["CountryProducts"] = data.ToArray();
    }
}
```

But i'm use two different methods for ajax, such as:

```
public ActionResult Details( int id )
{
    ...
    return View(model);
}

//for ajax request:
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Details( int id, string searchTerm )
{
    return new JsonResult()
               {
                   JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                   Data = GetFilteredDetailsData(id, searchTerm)
               };
}
```

Comment: I am trying to add my manufacturerId and Country Id in my View Ajax call How can I do this?

Comment: manufacturerId = $("#manufacturerId").val();
        searchField = "example";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET'
   , url: '@Url.Action( "Details", "ControllerName" )'
   , data: { id: manufacturerId, searchTerm: searchField }
   , success: function (resp) {
       // onSuccessFuntion
   }
        });